# Custom Block Pricing and Amendments

Tags: cpq, pricing

We have implemented the Block Tiers in CPQ but number of tiers in our products is greater than 50, as Pricing Method "Block Price" does not work when tiers are greater than 50 Here is the help article regarding the same https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000272895&language=en_US&type=1

So, we have implemented the block pricing with the help of Lookup Queries which worked fine for the block tiers more than 50, we have achieved that in folowing step
1) We have added the pricing method as default which is "list"
2) Created another field Block Quantity through which we are calculating Block prices.
3) Made the standard Quantity field on Quote line non editable and default as 1 so that the Total unit price will be same as list price.

All of this worked fine, but when we create the amendments with the products in which we have implemented custom block pricing we were not able to amend them because amendments depends on effective Quantity and it in turn depends upon the Standard CPQ Quantity field which we dont want to edit as we are calculating Quantity with the hep of "Block Quantiy", and when we do not change the Quantity the Quotelines don't sync to related opportuniies

I would Appreciate the guidance here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field Prior Quantity which populates on Amendment in Salesforce CPQ i have reset it to 0 in my case as i am not using standard Quantity, after doing this my effective quantity again goes to 1 and the product got synced to opportunity without changing the standard quantity field